# InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument (Session info: headless chrome=88.0.4324.182)?

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook

[image]

Hello people, i have trying to convert and html to pdf with pyhtml2pdf but i need use chromedriver to do it i try to solve these error installing the version that you see on the photo at the last row, but i dont know what can i do now!

here is the code that convert these on pdf :C

```
import os
from pyhtml2pdf import converter
base_dir = os.getcwd()
converter.convert(base_dir + "\\test.html", 'sample.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
import os
from pyhtml2pdf import converter

path = os.path.abspath('test.html')
converter.convert(f'file:///{path}', 'sample.pdf')
```

Comment: Ideally you would add an explanation for why this solution works.